# Rows and Column of Excel File

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

It is possible to write a code that specifying the rows and column of spread sheet in terms of NUMBERS and NOT LIKE (B2:D6)

Example:

```
excelSheet.Range("B2:D6").Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 255)
```

instead of B2 and D6 I want to write 5 rows and 3 column..

It is posible to write in vb.net 2003 code?

Comment: You need to accept some previous answers, If you do not accept answers people will not answer your questions.

Comment: what this question got to do with VB.NET?

Comment: It's called R1C1 notation, which stands for Row1Column1, meaning it is two integers separated by a comma, the first value being the row number (1-based in vba) and the 2nd value being the column number.  Mathias's answer demonstrates it effectively.

Answer (score 2):

This is C# and not VB, but this shouldn't be too hard to convert:

```
var firstCell = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[3, 3];
var secondCell = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[5, 7];
var cells = sheet.get_Range(firstCell, secondCell);
```

Comment: thanks for this reponse..
may i know how to have a border in all cells from A1 to E10..
and also, it is allowable to do this?

excelSheet.Cells(1, 10).BorderAround()

Comment: Mark, yes I have a fairly good idea how to do this, but I also see that you have asked 14 questions, but you haven't accepted a single answer on on any of them. You have to understand that this isn't very motivating.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Cells() instead of Range()

```
excelSheet.Cells(5,3).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 255)
```

Comment: @Mark - The easiest way to find the answer to questions like that is to record a macro, perform the action, then see what code it recorded. In the case of borders, you end up with a long series of statements that look something like ".Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous"